# How can I get height of ImageView in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView` and `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, that displaying `CardView` with `ImageView` and `TextView` in it. Images should be square, so in layout resource file I set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and now I need to set height equal to this width. I tried to do this in `Adapter`, that extends `RecyclerView.Adapter` in `onBindViewHolder` method, but getMeasuredWidth always returning 0. I'm setting adapter to RecyclerView in **Activity's** `onResume` method. How can I do this?

Comment: @Graeme, it's not working. As I understand, this method working when you set image source in layout resource file

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is the case when the `onResume` method is finished, the image is not set on UI screen yet because it will cost time.
A bitmap asynchronous framework might help you, like `xutils` or `[UniversalImageLoader][1]`. You can do the scale when the bitmap is downloaded completely, or you can get the image width from the server, there might be other solutions too.